# Fourier transform of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given a Lipschitz function $f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$, its derivative exists and is in $L^{\infty}$ almost everywhere under Lebesgue measure by Rademacher theorem. However, it is not continuous. Applying Fourier transform to the derivative, I wish to obtain somehow a $C^1$-version of $f$. Then I will do some calculation with the transformed version and then transform back.

I will work with the integral $$f(t)=\int_0^tf'(x)\,dx$$ and its transformed version is thus $$F(t)=\int_0^t\int_0^tf'(\xi)e^{-i\xi x} \,d\xi \,dx,$$ where I perform the fourier transform on the bounded domain $[0,t]$. However, I wish express the transformed version $F(t)$ as some operation of $f(t)$, i.e. rewritting into $F(t)=O(f(t))$, where $O$ is some mapping from space of $f(t)$ into space where $F(t)$ lives. Is it possible to find an expression for such mapping?

**My Goal:**
Once such mapping is found, I will investigate the continuity of the mapping. Then I will be able to approximate $F(t)$ by choosing an approximate sequence of $f(t)$ and an appropriate topology.

Comment: What's wrong with integrating by parts?

Comment: @Andrew I am still left with the term $e^{i \xi x}$ under the integral.

Comment: Should F(t) be the Fourier transform of f(x)? If that is your intention, your formula for F(t) is incorrect.

Comment: @timur Thanks, it's corrected.

Comment: "Its derivative is in $L^1$" you said, however, it seems to me that $f(x)=|x|$ is a counterexample to that. Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @quallenjäger Can't you just approximate your function with some polynomial and then you work on that. If you're looking for some features probably the coefficients of such polynomial will tell you something already.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It exists almost everywhere under Lebesgue measure. I should be more precise. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user8469759 Thank you for the suggestion. I thought in similar direction. The problem I have currently dealt with an approximation scheme of the derivative, which works only for continuous derivative. The reason why I am interested in the Fourier-Transform is because of the Levy continuity theorem: If I know that the approximation for the transformed derivative converges, (which is given because the transformed derivative is continuous) then the original version would also converge. This is the special feature, which plays a crucial role in my case.

Comment: What I meant is more like pick your $f$, approximate with some polynomial $p_n$ compute the fourier transform of $p_n$ and see what happens. So if $X$ is the functions space for $f$ you map/project in some $L^2$ space, and from there you compute the Fourier transform.

Comment: @user8469759 I see your point. I never thought in this direction. I will definitely try it out. Thanks.

Comment: My point is that $ (|x|)'= \pm 1$, so **it is not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$**.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok, you are right, it is badly formulated. Actually, I am only interested in the case with bounded domain $[0,t]$.

Comment: You can just write that $f'\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, which is true.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, Done.

Comment: The formula is still not correct. It should be something like $F(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\xi t}\int_0^tf'(x)dxdt$.

Comment: @timur What you wrote is a fourier transformation on $f(t)=\int_0^t f'(x)dx$, which is the function itself. I want a transformation on $f'(x)$.

Comment: Then the inner integral is not to t, it should be over the real line

Comment: @timur One can simply see $f(s)$ as a function with the support on $[0,t]$, i.e. defining $\tilde{f}(s)$ as $f(s)$ if $0 \leq s \leq t$ and 0 elsewhere and perform fourier transform on $\tilde{f(t)}$. It gives me the integral to t

Comment: That’s not true because your F depends on t. So t is not constant. I just don’t understand what you are trying to do. I might be able to help if I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration by parts:
$$
\begin{split}
F(t)
&=\int_0^t\int_0^tf'(\xi)e^{-i\xi x} \,d\xi \,dx\\
&=f(t)\int_0^te^{-ixt}dx+\int_0^t\int_0^tixf(\xi)e^{-i\xi x} \,d\xi \,dx\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-it^2}}{it}f(t)+\int_0^t\frac{(i-\xi)e^{-i\xi t}-1}{\xi^2}\cdot f(\xi)\,d\xi .
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Because f(x) is discontinuous, there is a problem with f'(x) at the jump points.  At these points f'(x) is a delta function with weight equal to the size of the jump.  Otherwise when you integrate f'(x), the result will be the a modification of the original function, with the jumps omitted, and the pieces between jumps parallel to the original function.

Comment: @herbsteinberg What do you mean parallel? Shouldn't it be the original function for the pieces between jumps just as a consequence of Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @timur Thanks for your answer. I see your point in the comment. Originally I was thinking of transforming the derivative by a fourier transform. The derivative $f'(\xi)$ is supported on $[0,T]$ with $t \leq T$. So I suppose the second integral should run over $[0,T]$. Further, I suppose the first summand in the second line it should be $e^{-ix\xi}$ right?

Comment: @timur What I was trying to do is to transform the derivative f' and then integrate to time $t$ to see how the transformed version $F(t)$ behaves compared to the original one $f(t)$. However, I just noticed that the second integration $dx$ might not make sense since the fourier transform $\int_0^T f'(\xi)e^{-i \xi x}d\xi$ might not be integrable with respect x. Is there any chance to set some conditions such that the fourier transformed version is integrable?

Comment: @quallenjäger: Integrating the Fourier transform and expecting it to correspond to integration in real space is somewhat "illegal." The corresponding operation in the Fourier space should be something like division by xi.

Comment: @quallenjager:  the fundamental theorem has a constant of integration.  When you have jumps, each piece of the integral of the derivative has a different constant of integration.  If you use one constant for the whole integral the picture will look as I described.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think there is a misunderstanding. My function $f(x)$ is Lipschitz-continuous. What is not continuous is the derivative.

Comment: @quallenjager  The confusion is a result of your original description.  "However, it is not continuous."  I interpreted "it" to mean the function, while you meant the derivative.